# nslookup fails but web access is OK

Tags: dns

I failed to get ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/js/rhino1_7R3.zip, so I did `nslookup mozilla.org`, which returns `Non-existent domain`. But it's OK when I visit https://developer.mozilla.org

Why is this happening?

I am in a LAN and the DNS is in the LAN.

Comment: Any firewall/proxy in your LAN?

Comment: @arsane proxy. But will the browser use proxy for name resolv?

Comment: Yes, you can either use proxy for name solving or local dns. I'm not sure which is the default way. I think the previous is reasonable, since for http proxy, the browser just send the url to proxy and leave the proxy to resolve address. As for one ip may map more than one domain name, so it's not reasonable to send the ip address to the proxy.